# What difference does adding 'who is' make in the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: clauses, gerund-clauses

A person **who is** willing to do the job would say yes easily.

Or

A person willing to do the job would say yes easily.

Are both the sentences grammatically sound ? What difference does adding 'who is' make in the meaning of the sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *A person* [*who is willing to do the job*] *would say yes easily*.
>
> [2] *A person* [*willing to do the job*] *would say yes easily*.

Yes, they are both fine. In both [1] and [2], the bracketed subordinate clause modifies "person", but the clauses belong to different categories.

Gerund-participial (*ing*) clauses when functioning as modifiers in noun phrase structure are semantically similar to relative clauses. The difference is grammatical in that they belong to different categories: a relative clause in [1], a non-finite clause in [2].

You may come across the term 'reduced relative clause' used to describe the subordinate clause in [2], but that term is best avoided since there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase (cf. the ungrammatical **a* *person who willing to do the job*).

Note: It would be more natural to use the word "readily" rather than "easily".